# (doom) emacs: lsp-mode not finding project root on sbt-start

Tags: emacs, sbt

I'm trying to run `sbt-start` with `lsp-mode` from within Doom Emacs from my Scala project, but when sbt starts up, it's in the home directory instead of where my `build.sbt` file is located. Has anyone experienced this before or does anyone know why this might be happening?

How do I specify to `lsp-mode` where the project root directory is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem was that I had a `project/` and `target/` folder in my $HOME directory, and simply deleting them enables `lsp-mode` to find the right project root.

Source: https://gitter.im/scalameta/metals?at=5c13d51d94d8cd0b9cc2e93f

Comment: I'm having this same problem; However, deleting the project and target folders along with the .metals, .bloop, and/or .bsp dot files in the home directory isn't solving the issue either.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, removing the project/ and target/ folder from the home directory is part of the answer. Also removing some dot files: .metals, .bloop, .bsp.

The unlock for me was using the following sequence of commands to get projects to find my project builds:
`M-x lsp-workspace-remove-all-folders`
next restart lsp-mode. This allowed me to reimport my projects correctly.